# Spark program fails while writing to a text file in local mode on windows

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-14

Getting exception while running a simple `spark` program in `Intellij` on `Windows`. When I ran the code in debug mode, found that the program is failing trying to execute below command.

```
D:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 0644 C:\Users\himanshu\git\SparkRDDs\target\output\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20170529130949_0027_m_000000_405\part-00000
```

This is where the code fails.

```
join.rdd.saveAsTextFile("file:///Users/himanshu/git/SparkRDDs/target/output/")
```

Stacktrace below -

> > 17/05/29 14:07:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 27.0 (TID 410)
> >         org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:798)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1206)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
> >             at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
Surprisingly in Eclipse, the program runs just fine.
```

Comment: Can you share the spark-submit command as well?

Comment: spark-submit --class org.himanshu.sparksql.JoinSparkSQL ./target/SparkRDDs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar src/main/resources/InputFile.txt src/main/resources/Address.txt

Comment: change  your output path as `"file://C:\\Users\\himanshu\\git\\SparkRDDs\\target\\output\\"` and let me know

Comment: Got below exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://C:\Users\himanshu\git\SparkRDDs\target\output\, expected: file:/// Tried with file:///, got same issue as above

Comment: try by removing `file://`  and just do `"C:\\Users\\himanshu\\git\\SparkRDDs\\target\\output\‌​\"`

Comment: No luck, got same exception.

Comment: can you share the output path that is created when you run through eclipse (full path)?

Comment: Realized the issue is because of winutils. Somehow it is not working for me in windows 10. I have tried downloading various versions online but does not work.

Comment: you said that it ran successfully in eclipse, so I don't think you would need winutils. just give the path where the spark user has access. That should work I guess

Comment: This issue is fixed. The problem was because of winutils. In windows 10, it wasn't working correctly because of some microsoft C++ libraries not updated. Once I updated those libraries, it started working correctly.

Comment: great to hear that :) answer what you've found to your question below